# Ignore Failure param type schema

Tags: go, swagger

I am defining an API and have my swagger annotations listed like

```
// deleteDB godoc
// @Summary      Deletes a Database
// @Description  Deletes a database in the k8s cluster with the required specification.
// @Tags         database
// @Param        DatabaseId path string true "The ID of the database"
// @Success      200  {string} string  "Database with provided ID has been deleted"
// @Failure      404  {null}    string  "Database with provided ID is not found"
// @Router       /v1/database/{DatabaseId} [delete]
func deleteDB(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // code to delete db
}
```

I am using [swaggo](https://github.com/swaggo/swag)

I then run `swag init` and the swagger.yaml file gets populated with

```
        "404":
          description: Database with provided ID is not found
          schema:
            type: "null"
```

This in turn looks like this in the Swagger UI

[image]

I do not want the schema to show. Just the code and the description. Like this

[image]

How can I change my Failure annotation to not include the schema ?